# Como usar uma variável do bloco try fora dele?

Tags: c#, exceção

Estou fazendo uma calculadora e com um tratamento de erros caso alguém tente dividir por zero.

```
try
    {
        double resultado = num1 / num2;
    }
catch (DivideByZeroException)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("IMPOSSÍVEL DIVIDIR POR ZERO");
    }
Console.WriteLine($"O resultado de {num1} ÷ {num2} é {resultado}");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É bem simples para este caso, não use exceção para resolver um problema de programação, isto é errado. Não deixe o erro acontecer:

```
if (num2 != 0) WriteLine($"O resultado de {num1} ÷ {num2} é {num1 / num2}");
else WriteLine("IMPOSSÍVEL DIVIDIR POR ZERO");
```

Se quiser insistir no erro, não tem porque separar parte da execução fora do `try`:

```
try {
    WriteLine($"O resultado de {num1} ÷ {num2} é {num1 / num2}");
} catch (DivideByZeroException) {
    WriteLine("IMPOSSÍVEL DIVIDIR POR ZERO");
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Exception/DivideByZero.cs).

Answer (score -1):

O que ocorre é, você está tentando utilizar uma variável em um contexto que ela não existe, por exemplo, não está declara, passada como parâmetro nesse contexto ou por fim não está declarada em um contexto acima que poderia proporcionar visibilidade, como ocorre para as variaveis num1 e num2.

Vejo que você tem duas opções, primeiro seria declarar a instrução que exibe o resultado dentro do escopo do try ou segundo, declarar a variável em um escopo acima ou no mesmo escopo que a num1 e num2.

Outra coisa que seria interessante caso ainda não saiba, é entender o que ocorre por trás do try catch e porque ocorre essa questão de escopos acarretando na visibilidade das variáveis.